Is there a fixed point for this sequence beyond 1?
I recently watched a video by the user Combo Class (link here) and he was analyzing what he called "glitch primes", where one writes a number in its prime factorization, and then replaces $p^n$ with $p+n$, multiplies the factors together, and continues this process iteratively. What is intriguing is that this process is fairly even in terms of whether the next number goes up or down.
I wanted to look into a variant of this process, what I call the "concatenated glitch primes". The process is as follows:

Take your number $n$ and write it as $\Pi_{1}^{k}{p_{i}^{e_{i}}}$, where $p_{i}$ are the primes appearing in its prime factorization, and $e_{i}$ are the relevant exponents. Note that if $e_i=1$, we would write it as such (thus, for example, $15=3^{1}\cdot5^{1} $).

To concatenate the base and the exponent, we must apply the formula $p_{i}\cdot10^{\lfloor{\log_{10}(e_i)}\rfloor+1}+ e_i$. This takes our $p_i$, shifts it by the amount of digits in $e_i$, and then adds $e_i$.

Once we have done this for each of the primes in the prime factorization, multiply them together.


The concatenation function is far more biased to create large numbers, since it grows mostly on the size of the digits. Take $n=30$: $30=2^1\cdot3^1\cdot5^1$, and so $a(30)=21\cdot31\cdot51=33201$. Thus, I realized quickly that, unless there was some sort of change in behavior for large $n$, that iterating this process wasn't too interesting.
However, I wanted to analyze $n$ such that $a(n)\leq{n}$. If we assume $a(1)=1$, since it is the empty product, we can find examples of n where $a(n)<n$. Take $n=32=2^5$; $25<32$. I've looked up to $n=36983$, and so far there are 328 such numbers, but there have not been any for which $a(n)=n$.
My main question is: is there some sort of exact, or, more likely, heuristic argument for the existence or nonexistence of such a fixed point in this process? The closest I've come is $a(6728)=6716$, which is only 12 under.
Check out A376254 and A376294 on the OEIS (they're drafts currently) if you're interested in fleshing out some of these ideas. The list of $n$ such that $a(n)<n$ is clearly infinite, since for small primes like $2$, the growth of powers of $2$ far outpaces the growth of digits in their exponents. But I really don't have a good idea if the prime factorization will ever line up in such a way that its concatenation is exactly equal.
Edit: I'm guessing that, if a number with $a(n)=n$ exists, it's very large. If we loosen the conditions, and analyze when $a(n)\mid{n}$, there is only one such number below 200,000: $n=93312=2^7\cdot{3^6}$, and $a(n)=27\cdot{36}=972$, with $\frac{93312}{972}=96$. Since the condition that I'm imposing is stricter, it follows that there should be even fewer numbers satisfying it.

Reminds me of the curiosity, $2^59^2=2592$.

A number that would satisfy $a(n) = n$ must have each of its coprime factors $p^k$ satisfy
$$ 10^{\lfloor\log_{10}(k)\rfloor+1}p + k,,\Big|,,p^k$$
...unclear if this helps.

@Mathemagician314 We have that $n=\prod_{i=1}^k {p_{i}^{e_{i}}}=\prod_{i=1}^k p_{i}\cdot10^{\lfloor{\log_{10}(e_i)}\rfloor+1}+ e_i$. This provides restrictions on the prime decomposition of each $p_{i}\cdot10^{\lfloor{\log_{10}(e_i)}\rfloor+1}+ e_i$, but (if $k\ge 2$) allows it to have other divisors than $p_i$.

Maybe I am wrong but i think there are 334 values under 36983
https://pastebin.com/ejkvAA8q

@SaiBhushan You’re probably right, I was doing it by hand initially and made some mistakes, someone else made some Mathematica code that likely agrees with what you found
